# ¿Cómo imprimir una matriz no cuadrada en java?

Tags: java

Muy Buenas, estoy trabajando datos en un arreglo del tipo matriz en java. El asunto es que la matriz no es cuadrada (tiene distinta cantidad de filas y columnas) y las columnas están dadas por una expresión dada en el código. Mi problema es que al imprimir mi matriz cada valor queda impreso hacia abajo y me gustaría obtener la forma de la matriz osea los valores impresos horizontalmente, me explico:

**ENTRADA**: Cantidad de filas y valores por posición.

**SALIDA**: Matriz no cuadrada impresa por pantalla.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class matriznc{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner filas = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de filas de la matriz: ");
    int f = filas.nextInt();
    int c = (2*f)-1; //Cantidad de columnas
    int matriz[][] = new int[f][c];
    for(int i=0;i<f;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese los valores: ["+i+","+j+"]");
        matriz[i][j]= teclado.nextInt();
        }
    }
//Imprimir el contenido para verificar
for (int i=0;i<f;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<c; j++) {
                System.out.println ("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");
                    if(j==(c-1)){
                        System.out.println("\n");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Los resultados que estoy obteniendo son del tipo:

```
Si ingreso como cantidad de filas f = 2
y a cada valor en la matriz le asigno un 1
el programa me imprime: 
[1]
[1]
[1]


[1]
[1]
[1]

Y lo que me gustaría obtener es del tipo: 

[1][1][1]
[1][1][1]
```

He tratado de corregirlo pero no llego a buenos resultados. Si es posible además me gustaría saber si es posible ingresar a la matriz caracteres que no sean números por ejemplo letras " a " o símbolos como " * ", traté de usar char cuando defino int matriz[ ][ ] pero me arrojaba error.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Cambiar `System.out.println ("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");` por `System.out.print ("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");` sin el salto de línea. `ln` , **Como su matriz está definida como enteros , no podrá añadir caracteres no númericos , a menos que cambie el tipo de la matriz**

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me retorna: [1][1][1][1][1][1]

Comment: Error mío!, me ha funcionado muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El Resultado obtenido es normal dado que al Imprimir los elementos de cada fila de la Matriz con `System.out.println()` muestra el elemento pero además de esto añade un salto de línea. Para evitar esto solo imprimir con `System.out.print()`

```
System.out.print("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");
```

Además el `if` dentro del `for` no es necesario, puede añadir un salto de línea al terminar los elementos de cada fila de la Matriz.

```
for (int i=0;i<f;i++) {
  for (int j=0;j<c; j++) System.out.print ("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");/* Elementos de Fila*/
  System.out.println(); /* Salto al finalizar los Elementos de la Fila i */
}
```

> Como su matriz está definida como enteros , no podrá añadir caracteres
>   no numéricos , a menos que cambie el tipo de Dato de la matriz

Answer (score 1):

También podrías haber puesto un salto de línea al completar cada fila

```
    for (int i=0;i<f;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<c; j++) {
                System.out.println ("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
     }
```

Algo así.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte pero no es necesario el if.

Comment: Solo puse el codigo que el tenia agregandole el salto de linea, naturalmente donde va el if debe de imprimir dicha matriz, con ese salto de linea la imprimira como el quiere.

Comment: Gracias por editarla solo era matener mas claro tu codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Por si deseas imprimir una matriz de cualquier tamaño con `JOptionPane` aquí te dejo el código, te funcionará perfectamente para cualquier matriz:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int nF = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese número de filas para la matriz"));
        int nC = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese número de columnas para la matriz"));
        int matriz[][] = new int[nF][nC];
        //Llenar matriz
        for (int i = 0; i < nF; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nC; j++) {
                matriz[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese valor para la posición [" + (i + 1) + "," + (j + 1) + "] de la matriz"));
            }
        }
        //Imprimir matriz
        String resultado = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < nF; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nC; j++) {
                resultado += matriz[i][j];
                resultado += "    ";
            }
            resultado += "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resultado);
    }
}
```